# using PHP and regex in cURL

Tags: php, regex, curl

I want to search a directory for a random file which has .png extension.I'm doing it via cURL so my script looks like this :

```
$url =  "http://www.google.com/images/logos/".$b;
```

and then just doing this :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

the problem is that i don't know how to set the value of `$b`.I tried this - `$b="{%[a-zA-Z0-9_-]%}.'.png'";` but obviously it doesn't work.

Thanks

Leron

Comment: Leron: Regular expressions work the other way round, to read from a string, not to create the string.

Comment: You mean to say that you want to download all the GOOGLE images that they use on Doodles?

Comment: No, I use this URL, because I find it in another question about cURL.In fact I just wanted to know if there's some way to fetch an unknown file in this way.And if there were eventually to make some loop and try take all the files.That's it.

Comment: Hakre - as you see i know too little about regual expressions is there a way to use them the way I want or any other opiton to make this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$test = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz....'; // put in all characters you want to test for

for($i=0,$len=strlen($test); $i<$len; $i++) {
  $b = $test[$i];
  $url =  sprintf("hxxp://www.google.com/images/logos/%s.png", $b);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  ...
}
```

This example is only for one letter. However if you want more letters, this can take very long until you tested for all files.

Let's say 23 possbile characters, length is

```
1: 23 urls
2: 529 urls
3: 12 167 urls
```

so for example 1-3 letters: 12 719 URLs to test. Just to give you the picture.

Comment: I also feel the need to point out that if you did that in a tight loop it would come at a significant cost to Google and http://www.google.com/robots.txt disallows spidering of that directory. Any way you look at it, it is being a poor net citizen.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I thought about regex, but obviously no way to use them the other way.

Comment: The loop is some kind of solution, but I don't think I'm gonna try it and all this is because today I start to learn cURL and want to see what I can and can not do.Google as I mentioned above whas from some other users example and I took it just for the test.

Comment: You might want to dig into *scraping* or *web scraping* a bit then.

Comment: Well, I see that regex is not an option here, and I understand why the loops is not either.Do you think there's another option besides those to to fetch an unknown file with .pgn extension for example?

Comment: Yes, thanks, obv. I need to read about web scraping in order to find a way.Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

I have an impression that you're not entirely understand how works Regular expressions.
Well,first you need have an input for matching with regex. 
Exemple:

```
$input = "hello, 123"; //I just need the digits part
$regex = @"\d+";
preg_match($regex, $input, $matched);
```

\d search by digits[0-9] on string,equivalents to [0-9]  or:

```
        for ($c = 0, $len = strlen($input); $c < $len; $c++)
        {
            $tmp = $input[$c];
            if ($tmp == '0' || $tmp == '1' || $tmp == '2' ||
               $tmp == '3' || $tmp == '4' || $tmp == '5' ||
               $tmp == '6'|| $tmp == '7' || $tmp == '8' ||
                $tmp == '9')
            {

               echo $tmp; 
            }
        }
```

if you want to download all google images,also check:

http://www.google.com/logos/
web crawler for extract link all images in this page:

```
<?
Header('Content-Type:text/plain');
$domain = "http://www.google.com/logos/";
$ch = curl_init($domain);
curl_setopt($ch ,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response  = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match_all("/<img\s+alt=\"(?<title>[^\"]+)\"\s+src=\"(?<url>[^\"]+)\"/", $response, $matched); 
print_r($matched); 
?>
```

Output:

```
  [title] => Array
        (
            [0] => Latest Google Logos
            [1] => Les Paul's 96th Birthday
            [2] => Dragon Boat Festival
            [3] => Richard Scarry's 92nd Birthday
            [4] => Republic Day
            [5] => Birthday of Ibn Khaldun
            [6] => Africa Day
            [7] => Jordan Independence Day
            [8] => Day of Slavonic Alphabet, Bulgarian Enlightenment and Culture
            [9] => Emile Berliner's 160th Birthday
            [10] => Doodle4Google US Winner
            [11] => 100th Birthday of Annie M.G. Schmidt
            [12] => Dame Nellie Melba's 150th Birthday
            [13] => 120th Birthday of Mikhail Bulgakov
            [14] => Paraguay's Independence Day
            [15] => Martha Graham's 117th Birthday. Animated by Ryan Woodward, choreographed by Janet Eilber, and danced by Blakeley White-McGuire.
//...



 [url] => Array
        (
            [0] => /images/feed-icon.gif
            [1] => /logos/2011/lespaul11-hp.png
            [2] => /logos/2011/dragonboat11-hp.jpg
            [3] => /logos/2011/scarry11-hp.png
            [4] => /logos/2011/republicday11-hp.jpg
            [5] => /logos/2011/ibn11-hp.jpg
            [6] => /logos/2011/africaday11-hp.jpg
            [7] => /logos/2011/jordan11-hp.png
            [8] => /logos/2011/slavonic_alaphabet11-hp.jpg
            [9] => /logos/2011/berliner11-hp.png
            [10] => /logos/2011/d4g11-matteolopez-HP.png
            [11] => /logos/2011/annieschmidt11-hp.jpg
            [12] => /logos/2011/nelliemelba11-hp.jpg
            [13] => /logos/2011/bulgakov11-hp.png
            [14] => /logos/2011/paraguay11-hp.jpg
            [15] => /logos/2011/graham11-hp.png
//....
```

and more

```
$urlToDownlaod = implode($domain, $matched["url"]);
$urlToDownlaod  = explode("\"", $urlToDownlaod);
print_r($urlToDownlaod);
```

Now here you have all urls of images hosted in google.com/logos
make a function for download

simple example:

```
function GetSrc($link) { 
$ch = curl_init($link);
curl_setopt($ch ,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
return curl_exec($ch); 
}

for($x = 0,$len = count($urlToDownlaod); $x < $len; $x++) {
     $fp = fopen("images/".$matched["title"][$x], "w");
     fputs($fp, GetSrc($urlToDownlaod[$x]);
     fclose($fp);
     flush();
}
```